# Eliminating non matching rows dependent on specific columns between two tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables where I want to match only on specific columns such as finding matching account numbers. I have that portion figured out however two of the columns are `calltime` and `calldate`. I  want to find all records that are a discrepancy (found in one but not the other). The issue is that there may be multiple calls in a day so the below is not working to find discrepancies.

Query 1 to get all calls where call date matches but is not found. The issue with this is that there may be a match for call date and call time but it's just not the current record being compared

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.VDMTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM DataopsTable
              WHERE DataopsTable.Citibank = VDMTable.Citiaccount
                AND DataopsTable.CallDate = VDMTable.Calldate
                AND DataopsTable.CallTime <> VDMTable.Calltime
```

Comment: Can you share input sample tables and expected output?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to only get answers that work for your system.

Comment: You say "there may be a match for call date and call time but it's not just the current record being compared".  Are you saying that there may be a record that matches on all 3 columns, but it's *still* not the right record, or are you saying that you want all the record in `VDMTable` that have *no* matches on the combination of all 3 columns? Where there simply isn't a record where the account matches, the date matches, and the time matches?

Comment: Yes, I want records that are in VDM table that have no matches on the combination of all 3 columns. For instance, account could match, call date could match but the call time isn't a match.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you select rows where **exists a mismatch**, and as you say, such mismatches are not really what you are looking for. What you are really interested in are rows for which **not exists a match**.

```
FROM dbo.VDMTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT null
    FROM DataopsTable
    WHERE DataopsTable.Citibank = VDMTable.Citiaccount
    AND DataopsTable.CallDate = VDMTable.Calldate
    AND DataopsTable.CallTime = VDMTable.Calltime
)
```

Comment: For this one, I'm not picking up entries where Citibank exists but does not have a match of Citiaccount in VDM. Any idea why?

Comment: The query gets you VDMTable rows that don't have a match in DataopsTable. If you also want to get DataopsTable rows that don't have a match in VDMTable you need a separate query. If you want a combined result, you can either `UNION ALL` the two results (but for this both queries must select the same columns) or `FULL OUTER JOIN` the results (probably with a pseudo `ON` clause like `ON 1 = 2`.